How to debug a ros2 command?
I have installed ros2 and this driver (build on windows 10) : https://github.com/ros-naoqi/naoqi_driver2
and that work all fine.
I want to see what's happening under the hood by debugging the c++ code.
How to do the debugging for example for the following command:
ros2 topic pub --once /speech std_msgs/String "data: hello"

using CLion IDE on Windows 10?
